JsonSchema ValidationError for an array
Code below throws a validation error: jsonschema.exceptions.ValidationError: '[1,1]' is not of type 'array'
I've checked with online validators and they seem fine - what have I done wrong?
import json
from jsonschema import Draft202012Validator

schema = json.loads(
    """
{
    "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
    "$id": "test",
    "type": "array"
}
"""
)

validator = Draft202012Validator(schema)

validator.validate("[1]")

Using jsonschema==4.23.0

"[1]" is a string.
I should have been using bare [1]
